# Can we define random forcing through Baire space?

Tags: logic, set-theory, forcing

We can talk about Cohen real both in $2^\omega$ and $\omega^\omega$ since all countable forcing notions are equivalent to $\mathbb{C}$, while in random forcing I've only seen random real in $2^\omega$. So, my question is：
1.In the random forcing definition, can we replace $2^\omega$ by $\omega^\omega$?
2.If 1 is wrong, can we talk about random real in $\omega^\omega$ by other ways?

Comment: As far as I know, the natural measure over $\omega^\omega$ induces the random forcing.

Comment: Since the random forcing is defined as Borel sets modulo the null ideal, and since *all* uncountable Polish spaces are Borel isomorphic. Yes.

Comment: Kanamori's book uses $\omega^\omega$ to define random in Chapter 11 if you want to see all the details spelled out.